# Linq emty result issue

Tags: c#, linq

I have such a query:

```
int cntR = res.Where(y => y.colour == "R" && y.branch == "QWERTY")
              .Select(z => new { z.Count })
              .SingleOrDefault().Count;
```

When result is not empty returned type is int.
But when it is empty one, I have an exception:

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

I can not understand why `SingleOrDefault()` returns null but not 0 default for int? I tried to use `DefaultIfEmpty(0)`, but it does not compiles.
Any ideas to avoid a problem?

Comment: You're not selecting an `int`, that' an anonymous class.  Try `z => z.Count` instead and remove the `.Count` at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you actually select the desired value instead of an anonymous class it should work as expected (assuming that the `Count` property is an `int`).

```
int cntR = res.Where(y => y.colour == "R" && y.branch == "QWERTY")
    .Select(z => z.Count)
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: replace `int cntR` with `var cntR` and `Count` can be any type.

Comment: @JamesCurran Yeah, but I meant  the default being 0 as well versus say `null` if it's actually an `int?`.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
int cntR = res.Where(y => y.colour == "R" && y.branch == "QWERTY")
              .Select(z => new { z.Count })
              .SingleOrDefault()?.Count ?? 0;
```

Note [null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) and [null-coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operator).

It will works only in C# 6.0 and higher.

Brief explanation how it works:

`SingleOrDefault()` returns object or null. So, OP trying to access `Count` from null. To prevent this, exists null-conditional operator, so `.SingleOrDefault()?.Count` returns null, if `SingleOrDefault()` returns null respectively. Null-coalescing operator, in this case, is used for default value, when we have null and expect that.

Comment: Was going to suggest something else, didn't think of this method though. +1! Should do the trick.

Comment: You should explain OP why you need the Null-conditional Operator when he selects an int-property: he selects an anonympous type with one int-property but the type itself is a reference type so can be `null`

Answer (score 0):

**I have another solution for you. Let's append a dummy data:**

```
int cntR = res.Where(y => y.colour == "R" && y.branch == "QWERTY")
               .Select(z => new { z.Count })
               .Concat(new[] { new { Count = 0 } })
               .First().Count;
```

Comment: In that case it's safe to just use `First` instead of `FirstOrDefault`.

Answer (score 0):

My own solution is:

```
cntR = (res.Where(y => y.colour == "R" && x.RpId == y.branch).Select(z => new { z.Count }).SingleOrDefault()!=null)
                ? res.Where(y => y.colour == "R" && x.RpId == y.branch).Select(z => new { z.Count }).Single().Count
                : 0;
```

It works =)

Comment: That's horrible, you're now iterating the collection twice when there's a match, not to mention the lack of readability and code duplication.  Literally use any of the other answers here instead.

Comment: I understand, so code: `int cntR = res.Where(y => y.colour == "R" && y.branch == "QWERTY")
    .Select(z => z.Count)
    .SingleOrDefault();` is the right solution!

Comment: Right is subjective, but I'd definitely say it's better.